# Why might we need multiple views based on a single viewpoint?

Tags: architecture, view

As defined in [Software Systems Architecture](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka4QO9kXQFUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) (chapter 3 - Viewpoints and Views) a view describes a particular aspect of architecture, and a viewpoint is a collection of patterns, templates, and conventions for constructing one type of view.
From this I do assume that only one view will be constructed from a viewpoint. But The book depicts in Figure 3-1 that multiple views can conform to a single viewpoints. How can this be explained? Or should I ask why would we need multiple views based on a single viewpoint?

[image: Figure 3-1, Software Systems Architecture, View and Viewpoints in Context]

Comment: `...multiple views can conform to a single viewpoint...` -- Why are you confused about this?  You can take a picture of a car from several different angles, but it is still the same car.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Viewpoint is a set of methods to generate a view. How could you use one set of methods and generate multiple views? Like taking multiple pictures from a car at the same angle and generating multiple views of that car?

Comment: The author is talking about engaging with stakeholders, not about writing code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm aware of that

Comment: Then I don't really understand your comment.  You generate multiple views the same way you generate the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At page 36 from the book, it provides a comparison between OO approach and Viewpoint definition, in order help understand the subject:

- A class definition provides a template for the construction of an object. An object-oriented system will include at runtime a number of objects, each of a specified class.
- A viewpoint provides a template for the construction of a view. A viewpoints-and-views-bases architecture definition will include a number of views, each conforming to a specific viewpoint.

EDIT: in this link there are examples of Viewpoints (https://www.viewpoints-and-perspectives.info/home/viewpoints/)

Considering the "Development" viewpoint: imagine that you project is for a complex Web solution that comprises two major components, a complex frontend web application and a complex Backend web service, with event different development teams for each one of them. You could, in the same Architectural Description for your project, create 2 "Development" Views to address some development/maintenance concerns of some specific stakeholder, one "Development" View for the frontend part (since it's complex enough to have it's own View) and another one for the Backend part.

Comment: Multiple objects of a single class makes sense, but multiple views from a single viewpoint doesn't make sense to me. Please explain that

Comment: According to the book, viewpoint is just a guideline with a set of templates and patterns that guide you in the task of creating a view. You could create multiple different views for different macro elementss of your system, all of them based on the same viewpoint. This might be uncommon, but depending on the project you could do that, if necessary.  Just like OO, depending on the class that you define, multiple objects of it can make no sense; depending on the viewpoint that you define (the idea of viewpoint was made generic by IEEE),  multiple views from it can make sense.